# Look at vs. watch

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

Here is the example that came up today:
My mother went to the park to _______ birds.

Would you use look at or watch, and why?

Comment: In general, "watch" implies a more conscious level of observation than does "look at".  And if your mother is a "bird watcher" then she might very well go to the park to watch birds (engage in the activity of "bird watching") rather than watch *the* birds.  If she's not a bird watcher, though, one would generally use "the" as suggested by FumbleFingers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :) English textbooks/lessons here in Japan try to be grammatical as possible but seem to miss the natural aspect of the language. Ah, well...

Answer (score 3):

Both are technically acceptable (neither is ungrammatical), but it depends what your *nuanced* meaning is. I would normally use them in differing situations. For example: I would go to a zoo to look at birds, but go to a park to watch them.

> My mother went to the park to ***look at*** birds.

This sounds to me that she goes to the park and sort of walks around to observe the birds as though they're an exhibit. She might be examining the different species or characteristics of various birds.

> My mother went to the park to ***watch*** birds.

In this one, it seems your mother goes to the park, sits down, and observes the birds from a distance. Maybe it's relaxing to her or something.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. There are some nuances to the `look` vs. `watch` vs. `see` that many people take for granted.

Look

- Used to ask for attention/volition

  > Look at/<strike>watch/see</strike> this cool website I found.

Watch

- Usually used for intense concentration

  > I closely <strike>looked at/saw</strike>/watched him count out the money.
- Usually used when watching things with motion

  > I <strike>watched/saw</strike>/looked at the painting for 5 minutes.
- Can be considered an activity

  > Do you do anything in the morning? I watch/<strike>see/look at</strike> people surf at the beach in the morning.

See

- Usually not used for motionless things

  > I've been looking at<strike>/seeing/watching</strike> this picture for about 5 minutes now. It's so beautiful.
- Not used for getting attention

  > Look at/watch/<strike>see</strike> my cool magic trick.